# Add a new term to a product attribute and set it in the product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

My custom taxonomy (WooCommerce attribute) already exists and I am using the following to add a new term to the taxonomy and associate it with my WooCommerce product:

```
wp_set_object_terms($product_id, array($omega_jahr), 'pa_years-of-construction');
```

When I use the following to call the 'pa_years_of_construction' for my product, I can see that the new terms have been saved:

```
$v = array_values( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_years-of-construction', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
```

However, when I check my product attributes in the backed and frontend of my website, the 'pa_years_of_construction' attribution isn't showing up.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 18):

Product attributes are a complicated custom taxonomy that needs much more than a simple line of code...

The following code will handle all cases for a pre-existing product attribute:

```
$taxonomy = 'pa_years-of-construction'; // The taxonomy

$term_name = '2009'; // The term "NAME"
$term_slug = sanitize_title($term_name); // The term "slug"

// Check if the term exist and if not it create it (and get the term ID).
if( ! term_exists( $term_name, $taxonomy ) ){
    $term_data = wp_insert_term( $term_name, $taxonomy );
    $term_id   = $term_data['term_id'];
} else {
    $term_id   = get_term_by( 'name', $term_name, $taxonomy )->term_id;
}

// get an instance of the WC_Product Object
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

$attributes = (array) $product->get_attributes();

// 1. If the product attribute is set for the product
if( array_key_exists( $taxonomy, $attributes ) ) {
    foreach( $attributes as $key => $attribute ){
        if( $key == $taxonomy ){
            $options = (array) $attribute->get_options();
            $options[] = $term_id;
            $attribute->set_options($options);
            $attributes[$key] = $attribute;
            break;
        }
    }
    $product->set_attributes( $attributes );
}
// 2. The product attribute is not set for the product
else {
    $attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();

    $attribute->set_id( sizeof( $attributes) + 1 );
    $attribute->set_name( $taxonomy );
    $attribute->set_options( array( $term_id ) );
    $attribute->set_position( sizeof( $attributes) + 1 );
    $attribute->set_visible( true );
    $attribute->set_variation( false );
    $attributes[] = $attribute;

    $product->set_attributes( $attributes );
}

$product->save();

// Append the new term in the product
if( ! has_term( $term_name, $taxonomy, $product_id ))
    wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $term_slug, $taxonomy, true );
```

Tested and works.

Comment: looks promising. Could you please explain why wp_set_object_terms() on its own isn't enough?

Comment: @RichardTinkler Product attributes are something much more complex than other custom taxonomies… They have their own Woocommerce additional table, they are also used for variations of a variable product and they add postmeta data too… Now if you go in your database and search for a define product id (that has product attributes set for it) in `wp_postmeta` table for the `meta_key` = `_product_attributes` you will better understand.

Comment: Thanks - seems to be working but is causing a MASSIVE server load resulting in a timeout. Any ideas?

Comment: I am about to try this out. Hopefully the load won't be too bad in my inventory syncing system I am building. I will update here!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: Your code is the only I found on the web that actually added the product attributes to a product, thanks! However, when terms of a product attribute are already set for a product, they won't be replaced/appended by this code, I have to manually remove the product attributes which terms should be updated.

Comment: Any chance you could expand this with an example about how to use this code to add MULTIPLE pre-existing attributes to a product? It works perfectly for one, but I'm trying to modify it so I can set two different attributes on a product at once.

Comment: Would also like to see how to add different attributes to more than one variation. I have tried and the second variation doesn't get the correct attributes set.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks !

Comment: @strarsis I had the same problem. If you want to replace the existing values, when you call $attributes= $product->get_attributes(); try to unset from the array of $attributes the existing taxonomy and set it again with the new values as if it was a new one, like LoicTheAztec suggests in else statement