# How to add custom attribute to all outofstock and all instock products?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

What I want to achieve is to add the custom attribute "instock" to all in-stock products and "outofstock" for products that out of stock.
Why? Because I want to add those attributes to filter plugin, that doesn't sort by stock status

I think construction will be something like this, but I don't know how to add attributes (

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'woocommerce_stock_availability_attributes', 1, 2);
function woocommerce_stock_availability_attributes( $availability, $_product ) {
   if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
       //some magic stuff
   }
  return $availability;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_availability', 'woocommerce_stock_availability_attributes', 1, 2);

function woocommerce_stock_availability_attributes($availability, $_product) {

    if (!$_product->is_in_stock()) {

        update_post_meta($_product->get_id(), 'custom_stock', "aminstock");

    } else {

        update_post_meta($_product->get_id(), 'custom_stock', "amoutofstock");
    }

    return $availability;
}
```

Try adding a custom meta to the product and check.

Comment: well, yeah,  it adds data to product meta, but it doesn't work )
And it doesnt add attributes to products.

Comment: As said here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53705122/add-a-new-term-to-a-product-attribute-and-set-it-in-the-product-in-woocommerce)
Product attributes are a complicated custom taxonomy that needs much more than a simple line of code...